# Check file extension BASH

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to compare 2 files that have the same name and the same contents but I only want to keep one of them. 
Lets say I have the following

```
/root/dir1/file1.doc
/root/dir1/file1.pdf
```

I only want to keep the .doc file what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: `rm /root/dir1/file1.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

From the `dash` manpage (and I believe all `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` "inherit" these features):

> ${parameter%word}     Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.  The word is
>   expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results
>   in parameter, with the smallest portion of the suffix matched by the
>   pattern
>                              deleted.
>
> ${parameter%%word}    Remove Largest Suffix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results
>   in parameter, with the largest portion of the suffix matched by the
>   pattern
>                              deleted.
>
> ${parameter#word}     Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then
>   results in parameter, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched
>   by the pattern
>                              deleted.
>
> ${parameter##word}    Remove Largest Prefix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results
>   in parameter, with the largest portion of the prefix matched by the
>   pattern

In practice:

```
shortSuff(){ printf '%s\n' "${1#*.}"; } 
#^applies the string op to the $1 positional parameter
#`printf '%s\n'` is like `echo` but doesn't break on e.g., hyphen-prefix arguments

file=/root/dir1/file1.doc
[ shortSuff "$file" = doc ] && echo "Yes, the short suffix is doc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a short script to do this for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXT="${1}"
if -z "${EXT}"; then EXT=".doc"; fi
TD="$(mktemp -d)"
mv ./*"${EXT}" "${TD}"
rm ./*
mv "${TD}"/* .
rmdir "${TD}"
```

Assuming your script is called `keep_copy.sh`, you would call it as follows: `keep_copy.sh .doc`.

Comment: This is the worst way to solve this problem I could think of on short notice. Been reading too much of the Daily WTF...